# change dir. in unix based OS with special char. in folder-name

Tags: linux

I want to go inside a dir. in an ubuntu server.

Problem : **The name of the folder is `@w$#`**

It's in /Volumes/

```
$ pwd
/Volumes

$ ls -a
.       ..      @w$#        hdd
```

I can't go inside the @w$# .

NOTES :

Also, **tab completion** OR **drag and drop** is not gonna work. ( src : https://askubuntu.com/a/101602)

Also, I think I shouldn't delete **/hdd** or even the **/Volumes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround the directory name with single quotes:

```
cd '@w$#'
```

That will escape the special characters that it contains: `@`,  `$`, and `#`.

Comment: tab will wirk if you gonna use cd "@ AND PRESS TAB or even only cd" tab should do the same

Comment: this one worked... thanks @Nasir Riley

Answer (score 1):

Generically, the answer is to escape the special characters.  This can be done, as Nasir mentioned above, by enclosing the entire thing in single quote marks.  It can also be done by prefacing any special characters with a backslash character.

```
cd \@w\$\#
```

Also as others have mentioned, if you escape the first character, then tab completion will work.  In this particular case, with tab completion, the @ is seen as a special networking character, and so tries to complete as one of various hostnames.  If you get passed the @ to the w, it realizes it isn't a network completion and works correctly.